# Time-series plot for different seasons in the same plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I would like plot a time series data for different seasons of the year (grouped as cold or warm) in the same plot and identify the two periods. How can I do that?

Reproducible data follows:

```
library(gamair) 
data(chicago) 
chicago$date<-seq(from=as.Date("1987-01-01"), to=as.Date("2000-12-31"),length=5114)
data.cold <- subset(chicago, quarters(date) %in% c("Q1", "Q4"))
data.warm <- subset(chicago, quarters(date) %in% c("Q2", "Q3"))
```

These codes below will create two separate plots for the two periods:

```
with(data.cold,plot(date,death,pch=".", ylab= expression("Mortality Count"), main = "Daily Mortality in cold season"))
with(data.warm ,plot(date,death,pch=".", ylab= expression("Mortality Count"), main = "Daily Mortality in warm season"))
```

This following code creates one plot, but there is no clear demarcation of the two periods. My wish is to create identifiable plot for the two periods in a single plot.

```
with(chicago,plot(date,death,pch=".", ylab= expression("Mortality Count"), main = "Daily Mortality from  1987-2000"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `?points`:

```
with(data.cold,plot(date,death,pch=".", ylab= expression("Mortality Count"), main = "Daily Mortality in cold season"))
with(data.warm ,points(date,death,pch=".", ylab= expression("Mortality Count"), main = "Daily Mortality in warm season", col="red"))
legend("topright", c("cold", "warm"), fill=c("black", "red"))
```

Does that work for you?